# Send mail from a container using a postfix container

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, postfix-mta

I'm using an application hosted on a docker container.
This application executes bash scripts / instructions to send mails.
I made another container which executes Postfix as a SMTP Relay.

I want to send mails from my application container by using a bash script using my Postfix container as a relay.

I tried to connect with SSH from my application container to my Postfix container. But that doesn't seem to work.

How can i make it so a script executed in my application container can use my Postfix relay while not allowing anything outside of the docker network, or even better, to only allow some containers, to send mails from this relay.

EDIT 1 : Docker-compose files

Application docker compose :

```
version: "3.4"
volumes:
  [...]

services:
application:
    restart: always
    build: ./application
    depends_on:
    - mariadb
    container_name: application
    volumes:
      [...]
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "5669:5669"
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        window: 300s
    links:
      - mariadb
    external_links:
      - smtp-server

  mariadb:
    restart: always
    image: mariadb
    command: mysqld --sql-mode=ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
    container_name: application-mariadb
    volumes:
    [...]
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "yes"
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        window: 300s
```

Here's my docker compose for my SMTP server :
    version: "3.4"

```
services:
 postfix:
   restart: always
   build: ./postfix
   container_name: smtp-server
   deploy:
     restart_policy:
        window: 300s
```

Answer (score 0):

{a quick response, because I "cicle" in my work ... and I'm taking 10 minutes of clear my mint, I hope it serves you}

Are you using "docker-compose" ?, could you give an example of your YML file? (a little more context)

[you can not connect to by ssh to a container unless you have "[supervisor](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/dockerizing-nginx-and-ssh-using-supervisord/)" installed,which I do not recommend at all.]

from what I see, you only need to make private networks; You could use this:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

to hide everything, I also recommend using a load balancer / Inverse Proxy like [TRAEFIK](https://traefik.io/) (if they have access to port 80 or 443 in some clear way this ...)

so you only expose 1/2 port(s) (80 + 443 for example) and everything else is protected by your reverse proxy

Watch as I separate the networks as you need the different containers.

- bash have access to db and smtp
- db does not have access smtp neither nginx
- nginx have access to bash
- nginx have access to proxy network to expose 80 and 443
- no other container is exposed to the outside more than nginx

--

```
version: "3"
services:
  bash:
####### use hostname "smtp" as SMTP server
    image: bash
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - smtp_internal_network
      - internal_network
      - data_network
    volumes:
      - ../html:/var/www/html
    restart: always
  db:
    image: percona:5.7
#    ports: # for debug connections and querys
#      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ../db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - data_network
    restart: always
  smtp:
    image: mwader/postfix-relay
    environment:
      - POSTFIX_myhostname=smtp.domain.tld
    networks:
      - smtp_internal_network
    restart: always
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ../html:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - external_network
      - internal_network
  labels:
      - "traefik.backend=nginx_${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}"
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${FRONTEND_RULE}"
      - "traefik.frontend.passHostHeader=true"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
   restart: always
   depends_on:
      - db
      - bash


networks:
  external_network:
    external:
      name: traefik_proxy
  internal_network:
    driver: bridge
  smtp_internal_network:
    driver: bridge
  data_network:
    driver: bridge
```

---

Edit:

```
version: "3"
volumes:
  [...]

services:
 ####### use hostname "smtp" as SMTP server in your application
  application:
    restart: always
    build: ./application
    depends_on:
    - mariadb
    volumes:
      [...]
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "5669:5669"
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        window: 300s
    networks:
      - smtp_external_network
      - data_network

  mariadb:
    restart: always
    image: mariadb
    command: mysqld --sql-mode=ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
    networks:
      - data_network
    volumes:
    [...]
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "yes"
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        window: 300s

networks:
  smtp_external_network:
    external:
      name: [ReplaceForFolderParentNameOfSmtpYmlWithoutSquareBrackets]_smtp
  data_network:
    driver: bridge

--- (in your other file)

services:
 smtp:
   restart: always
   build: ./postfix
   networks:
     - smtp
   deploy:
     restart_policy:
        window: 300s

networks:
  smpt:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: maybe that new YML will serve you

Comment: I see a huge problem.
If i create another docker compose file, i can access the network between my mariadb and application container.
I want this network to be restricted to my application and mariadb.

Comment: I did not understand the problem very well, but, because you do not try to limit the "docker" application only to the "ROOT" user, that way you have access to ROOT, and only you can raise new instances in that server. (obviously only you should have access to root) //// Secondly, please, do not use any database engine with docker in production, requests for iops to kernel are slower in docker.  use a dedicated and scalable Amazon or google cloud service for database

Comment: I want to restrict and control network accesses on my containers.
I want some containers to comunicate with some other containers.
But i don't want to let it open. This is to avoid corrupt or hacked containers to be dangerous for the rest of my containers.

Comment: My knowledge of docker up here came, as far as I know: the networks are already isolated from each other, if you want to improve security in case an attacker takes control of a process, and in turn, detects that it is in a docker image, and use some vulnerability to take host control via kernel, it would be best to use namespaces: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/

If you find how to solve your dilemma, comment it so that we all learn.

Comment: I found a way, it seems.
Each time your create services with a Docker-Compose file, Docker seems to create a default network tied to this Docker Compose. This is a Network that you can't access from another Docker Compose file. I will test this tomorow.

Comment: Good luck with that test

Comment: Ok so it seems my containers are on the same network. But i want to send a mail from my app container using my relay container using bash, how to do so ?